# Create GitHub Action how to get the latest tag of branch?

Tags: javascript, git, github, github-actions, github-api

Im currently creating an GitHub action and I got in trouble get the latest tag in branch. I know how to do it with git command but for octokit something like that didn't exist. I allready got all tags inside the repo.

The exec function didn't seem to work. Any solution to that would be nice.

```js
const exec = require('@actions/exec');

async function execute(command) {
  let stdout = '';
  let stderr = '';

  try {
    const options = {
      listeners: {
        stdout: data => {
          stdout += data.toString();
        },
        stderr: data => {
          stderr += data.toString();
        }
      }
    };

    const code = await exec(command, undefined, options);

    return {
      code,
      stdout,
      stderr
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      code: 1,
      stdout,
      stderr,
      error: err
    };
  }
}

async function run() {

//...

const resFetch = await execute('git fetch --tags');
core.info(JSON.stringify(resFetch));
const resTag = await execute('git describe --tags --abbrev=0');
core.info(JSON.stringify(resTag));

/* Output:
{"code":1,"stdout":"","stderr":"","error":{}}
{"code":1,"stdout":"","stderr":"","error":{}}
*/
//...
```